# Add New External Git Repository Connection - Visual Studio Team Services

Tags: git, azure-devops

I am trying to add an external git repository to a visual studio team services build process but always receive an error during build:

> Starting clone
>
> Request failed with status code: 404
>
> Prepare repository failed with exception.

On the page [Specify the repository](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vs/alm/build/define/repository) I can only read

> Fill in the Add New External Git Repository Connection dialog box.

But how? Searching the internet I could not find any help. Trying out different settings - nothing helped.

What do I have to enter for a repository located at for example

https://username@bitbucket.org/repodir/repo.git

In the build definition within the repository tab I enter

Repository type: External Git
Connection:

Add new external git repository connection (setting up a connection)

> Server URL: https://bitbucket.org
>
> User name: myUserName
>
> Password/Token Key: ********
>
> Repository name: repodir/repo.git
>   ( I also tried Repository name: repodir/repo )

What ever I try - I always get the error message. Using command line, I can easily clone the repository. How can I enable Team Services to clone an external repository? I think I am missing something big here...

Thanks a lot for any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok. I finally managed to clone an external git repository in a build process in visual studio team services/ visual studio online. The important points are:

- On the repository tab one can leave the repository name blank (will be entered automatically after saving later)
- There must already be a commit on the branch mentioned at 'Default branch'
- In the dialog 'Add new external git repository connection' (or later the 'Update authentication for repositoryName') the server URL is the whole url, something like: 'https://...myRepo.git'

I tested this with a private bitbucket repository.

Comment: As the 'repository name' mentioned in point one can be any name you like (just found that out) and I tried the whole git url earlier and my repository was not empty, it seems that I experienced a team services failure/ bug while trying to clone. That's the dark side of the cloud - if the guys in the cloud are breaking things one can nothing do but wait... :)

Comment: Should the url repository be like 'https://username@bitbucket.org/repodir/repo.git' ? I'm not able to connect to the repo for some reason... Stuck with 'Connecting to service using credentials' message. No errors at all.

Comment: does visual studio online provides feature to navigate the source if we use external git source? I found that it is not providing feature to navigate through source. I just need to write full path of source.